# JPA persisting a new entity with embedded id that has user supplied values

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

How do I setup entities to persist when the embedded id values are not sequenced, or generated, but supplied by user input? The case is that I have a CustomDeviceType that has a list of CustomDeviceModels. When a user creates a new CustomDeviceType they will supply the attributes, including the number used for the ID. The same goes for each CustomDeviceModel attached to the CustomDeviceType.

Because the table devmodels has a composite primary key of (dev_type,model_nbr) I created an EmbeddedEd for CustomDeviceModel. When I try to persist the CustomDeviceType I get the following error:

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.etisoftware.manager.beans.cborg.devices.CustomDeviceModel with id com.etisoftware.manager.beans.cborg.devices.DeviceModelId@de70
```

Which makes sense from Hibernates point of view since DeviceModeId has values it should exist in the database. But it doesn't.

So given this table setup, which I cannot change. How do setup my entities so that I can save new CustomDeviceModels?

I have two tables devtypes and devmodels:

```
CREATE TABLE devtypes (
    dev_type integer NOT NULL,
    dev_desc nchar(16) NOT NULL,
    off_premise integer NOT NULL,
    unrouteable integer DEFAULT 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ,
    custom_models integer DEFAULT 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ,
    force_case nchar(1) DEFAULT 'U                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ',
    has_siblings integer DEFAULT 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ,
    PRIMARY KEY (dev_type)
);


CREATE TABLE devmodels (
    dev_type integer NOT NULL,
    model_nbr integer NOT NULL,
    model_desc nchar(20),
    cablecard integer DEFAULT 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ,
    ont_type integer DEFAULT 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               NOT NULL,
    ont_port_type nchar(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (dev_type,model_nbr)
);

ALTER TABLE devmodels
    ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (dev_type) 
    REFERENCES devtypes (dev_type);
```

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "devtypes")
public class CustomDeviceType
{
  @Id
  @Column(name = "dev_type")
  private Integer          number;

  @Column(name = "dev_desc")
  private String           name;

  @Column(name = "unrouteable")
  private Boolean          unrouteable;

  @Column(name = "off_premise")
  private Boolean          offPremise;

  @Column(name = "has_siblings")
  private Boolean          hasSiblings;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "deviceType", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Set<CustomDeviceModel> deviceModels;

  // Setters

}



@Entity
@Table(name = "devmodels")
public class CustomDeviceModel
{
  @EmbeddedId
  private DeviceModelId id;

  public CustomDeviceModel()
  {
    id = new DeviceModelId();
  }

  @Column(name = "model_desc")
  private String           name;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "dev_type")
  @MapsId("deviceTypeNumber")
  private CustomDeviceType deviceType;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "deviceModel", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "dev_type"), @JoinColumn(name = "model_nbr") })
  private CustomDeviceTypeConfig deviceConfig;

  public Integer getNumber()
  {
    return id.getNumber();
  }

  public void setNumber(Integer number)
  {
    id.setNumber(number);
  }

  public void setDeviceType(CustomDeviceType deviceType)
  {
    this.deviceType = deviceType;
    id.setDeviceTypeNumber(deviceType.getNumber());
  }

  public CustomDeviceTypeConfig getDeviceConfig()
  {
    return deviceConfig;
  }

  public void setDeviceConfig(CustomDeviceTypeConfig deviceConfig)
  {
    this.deviceConfig = deviceConfig;
    id.setDeviceTypeNumber(deviceConfig.getDeviceModel().getDeviceType().getNumber());
    id.setNumber(deviceConfig.getDeviceModel().getNumber());
  }

  // other setters

}




@Embeddable
public class DeviceModelId implements Serializable
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 5215223205194404431L;

  private Integer           deviceTypeNumber;

  @Column(name = "model_nbr")
  private Integer           number;

  public Integer getNumber()
  {
    return number;
  }

  public void setNumber(Integer number)
  {
    this.number = number;
  }

  public Integer getDeviceTypeNumber()
  {
    return deviceTypeNumber;
  }

  public void setDeviceTypeNumber(Integer deviceTypeNumber)
  {
    this.deviceTypeNumber = deviceTypeNumber;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode()
  {
    return new HashCodeBuilder().append(deviceTypeNumber).append(number).toHashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(final Object object)
  {
    if (object instanceof DeviceModelId)
    {
      final DeviceModelId other = (DeviceModelId) object;
      return new EqualsBuilder().append(deviceTypeNumber, other.getDeviceTypeNumber()).append(number, other
          .getNumber()).isEquals();
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this was an error on my part. I forgot to add the cascade type.

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "deviceType", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set deviceModels;